# How can I add more features to my wysiwyg in Shopify Blog articles?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

My current options in the Shopify WYSIWYG are very limiting. I'd like to be able to add icons, buttons, columns, etc.

Is there an app that can give me this functionality?